# Nginx - How can I check if an incoming request in a location contains a set of headers?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I am a newbie in server stuffs. Recently I had configured a server with Nginx and found all working fine. Now I need to check the requests in a location that it contains all the custom headers. I just need to check the header name only and no need to worry about the values. I had tried with `map` directive but it seems I need to write it for each of headers (Pasting the code below).

```
map $http_custom_header $headerfound {
        default "access-denied";
        Test "access-granted";

    }
```

Is there any method to catch all headers at once and check against a set of header names ?

Comment: Do you now names of all custom headers? You can simply add one map whith all headers by: map "$http_header1:$http_header2:$http_header3" $headerfound

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18972508 "Nginx: Reject request if header is not present or wrong") answer your question?

Comment: @unlo Yeah, i have the list of names of all custom headers. You mean I can give a colon seperated list of header names in map function ? Also do I need to take care of values ? Can you please update as an answer

Comment: @ckujau I had went through it. But it seems I need to write that much map functions and if clauses for each of my headers.

Comment: @AkhilSundar you can try to merge all headers like this: map $http_custom_header1$http_custom_header2$http_custom_header3 $allheadersfound;  if you really need to check all headers to exist.